# Do investigations get cycled out without manually deleting them?

Tags: monster-hunter-world

There appears to be a maximum of 250 investigations. Do I have to manually delete ones I don't want or am I safe to just leave them to be replaced once the list is full?

Assuming they get rotated out either way, if I've accepted an investigation so it appears in the quest list, can that still get cycled out and remove my access to it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

My understanding is that old investigations do get removed to make room for new ones, unless you have registered them.
So as long as you have registered the ones you want, I don't think you have to worry about it.

Comment: It's confirmed that registered investigations are kept even as the entire pool fills and older ones get deleted automatically.